# Ambiguity in MongoDB documentation-Model.find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm doing [this tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/5a0673c880aca7739224ee21/mean-stack-angular-5-crud-web-application-example) and at step **5. Create Routes for Accessing Book Data via Restful API** it says

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Book = require('../models/Book.js');

/* GET ALL BOOKS */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Book.find(function (err, products) {//this is the line I'm having trouble understanding
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(products);
  });
});
```

What I don't understand is, if I'm reading the [Mongoose.find() documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find) correctly, at least one mandatory parameter of 'options' needs to be passed BEFORE a callback function is passed. This seems to skip the mandatory parameter.

Is the tutorial inconsistent with the documentation?

**What I have tried:**

reviwing the documentation @
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md

but that doesn't mention optionality of the first first parameter.

Comment: Did you try the code ? You need to pass options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose builds a MongoDB `.find()` query out of your `Book.find()`, and if you [look at Mongoose source](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L1538), you'll see that `Model.find` checks if the first parameter of `find` is a function and if yes, passes that function as the callback for the MongoDB query builder on line 1566.

That way an empty `conditions` object is passed by Mongoose to the MongoDB `find` function along with your callback, which returns all books in your case.

Comment: OK that's fine thanks...is the documentation I refer to in the original post strictly correct in that case? I was expecting a non-function parameter to be passed FIRST no matter what...

Comment: I suppose it can be a little misleading, as it says you have to pass an object, even though its also possible to just pass the callback function.

Comment: Misleading? Agreed! Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

`[options]` are optional so not mandate to pass however statement  `The conditions are cast to their respective SchemaTypes before the command is sent.`  in documentation looks inconsistent with actual `.find()` function.

> > `Model.find()`
> >
> > **`Parameters`**
> >
> > `conditions «Object»`
> >
> > `[projection] «Object|String»` optional fields to return, see`Query.prototype.select()`
> >
> > `[options] «Object»` optional see Query.prototype.setOptions()
> >
> > `[callback] «Function»`
> >     Returns:
> >     «Query»
> >     Finds documents
> >
> > The conditions are cast to their respective SchemaTypes before the command is sent.

For more deeper you can look to [source code.](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L1538)

> > Every argument of `.find()` function is firstly checked if it is a function or not.====>         `(typeof parameter=== 'function')`